# recommendations on a book to learn about spacing

Tags: html

i am interested to learn more about spacing, offset, and stuff that applies to text and tables. i think in the beginning it probably just applied to html, but now these concepts are universal. please recommend a tutorial or book to help me understand these spacing concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking with Type by Ellen Lupton

http://www.papress.com/thinkingwithtype/